# Menus library with PDCurses

Tags: c++, ncurses, pdcurses

I'm currently learning to program with NCurses/PDCurses by reading this tutorial: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/ But when I get to chapter 17 which is about the menus library, I'm getting kind of stuck. `#include <menu.h>` doesn't work, and I can't find menu.h in the pdcurs34 folder. Is there a way to add the menus library (menu.h) to PDCurses? (PS: I'm using MS Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 0):

The menu library is part of the ncurses package I don't think the menu library will work with pdcurses but you could try extracting it from the ncurses source and compiling against pdcurses.

The latest ncurses: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-5.9.tar.gz