# menu.h && form.h doesn't exist in pdcurses

Tags: c, menu, pdcurses

Writing C in Visual Studio 2010, I have downloaded the pdcurses34 from the sourceforge. After i compiled the lib for win32 as the documentation says i configured the visual studio to use this library.

Then started to read [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) HOWTO for ncurses

Some time later i thought to make a simple app with menu option as the HOWTO  considers on chapter 17.

The result is that neither menu.h nor form.h files exists.
I search into the folder of pdcurses and nothing found.

So i am asking , which is the way to create menu (basically) and forms with pdcurses?

Answer (score 1):

Since they doesn't come with pdcurses, i guess you would have to create them yourself.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912260/menus-library-with-pdcurses) suggests compiling them against the pdcurses source code, but there was no more feedback.